# Django: Best practices for database design

Tags: database, django, database-design, architecture

I'm starting a project and i've decided to use Django.

My question is regarding to the creation of the database. I've read the tutorial and some books and those always start creating the models, and then synchronizing the DataBase. I've to say, that's a little weird for me. I've always started with the DB, defining the schema, and after that creating my DB Abstractions (models, entities, etc).

I've check some external-pluggable apps and those use that "model first" practice too.

I can see some advantages for the "model-first" approach, like portability, re-deployment, etc.

But i also see some disadvantages: how to create indexes, the kind of index, triggers, views, SPs, etc.

So, How do you start a real life project?

Comment: I plan my db schema, then implement it through a django model.  You can create indexes in django or through your db backend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Triggers, views, and stored procedures aren't really a part of the Django world. It can be made to use them, but it's painful and unnecessary. Django's developers take the view that business logic belongs in Python, not in your database.

As for indexes, you can create them along with your models (with things like `db_index` and `unique_together`, or you can add them later via database migrations using something like South.

Comment: +1 good answer. Thanks. Now, i ask: Don't you ever use triggers, SPs or views? Can real world apps exist without those things? Please don't misunderstand me, I'm new in Python+Django world. I come from Big Architectures Java Apps, and we rely on those DB stuff.

Comment: +1 for use of South.  You can manage your indexes and the like using migrations, making life much easier.

Comment: Oracle developers insist that one indisputable principle of database design is primary keys should be immutable. They don't really have a good theoretical reason for that claim. It just happens that Oracle doesn't support `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. I think your opinion would be different if Django had supported triggers, views, stored procedures, check constraints, and deferred constraints from the beginning.

Comment: @Catcall But I didn't say at all that you should never use these things. I just said that Django doesn't make it easy, and that Django developers get along just fine without them.

Answer (score 7):

Mostly we don't write SQL (e.g. create index, create tables, etc...) for our models, and instead rely on Django to generate it for us.

It is absolutely okay to start with designing your app from the model layer, as you can rely on Django to generate the correct database sql needed for you.

However, Django does provide various functions for you to replicate these database functions:

- triggers: [Django code or MySQL triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061304/django-code-or-mysql-triggers)
- indexes: can be specified with `db_index=True`
- unique constraints: `unique = True` or `unique_togther = (('field1', field2'),)` for composite unique constraint.

The advantage with using Django instead of writing sql is that you abstract yourself away from the particular database you are using. In other words, you could be on `SQLite` one day and switch to `PostgresQL` or `MySQL` the next and the change would be relatively painless.

**Example:**

When you run this:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Django automatically creates the tables, indexes, triggers, etc, it needs to support the models you've created. If you are not comfortable with django creating your database for you, you can always use:

```
python manage.py sqlall
```

This will print out the SQL statements that Django would need to have in order for its models to function properly. There are other `sql` commands for you to use:

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#sql-appname-appname

Comment: I think this is right. But, i always say that it's not common to switch databases. I mean, everybody take this like a big advantage, but rarely happens. Good answer BTW +1

Comment: For what it's worth (and since this thread is 2+ years old, not much) I just recently switched two projects I had started off as SQLite (so I could just get them up and running on a minimal system) to use Postgres for performance/multiprocess reasons.